# Template Layout vs Includes Priority

Tags: php, silverstripe

I am trying to override the `silvershop/templates/Layout/Product.ss` template in [the SilverShop module](https://github.com/silvershop/silvershop-core) in `themes/default/Includes/Product.ss` but SilverStripe isn't picking up my template.

SilverShop uses `Product` as a Layout, I would like to <s>use</s> *redefine* it as an Include.

Does anyone know how to make SilverStripe load my template via <% include Product %>?

---

**Clarification:** I'm not creating a layout, I'm creating an include. Excusing my specific example of `Product`:

- Why does `<% include %>` default to Layout over Includes, despite `Includes/Product.ss` residing in mysite and `Layout/Product.ss` residing elsewhere (a plugin)?
- Why does `<% include %>` even look for layouts (isn't that the idea of Includes)?

I see this oversight causing issues with plugins/external code practising something akin to ["Cybersquatting"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cybersquatting) (but more generally) useful filenames. There is a push to [namespace the core classes](https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-framework/issues/3548), one of the reasons being something similar to this I assume

Comment: Layouts are used for any subclass of SiteTree, includes are intended for partials. So any Product would need an /templates/Layout/Product.ss since that is called from /templates/Page.ss

Can you provide more info about the use case?

Comment: https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/3.4/developer_guides/templates/template_inheritance/#template-manifest  This shows the priority of the templates. Also don't forget to ?flush=all

Comment: You can "include" any template, it's not limited to files from the `Includes` directory. If you want to override the template from silvershop, follow wilrs answer.